# Connect two tables in a new one

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

**Situation:**

I have got 2 tables. A table with process steps `tbl_uo_step`, and a table with all media `tbl_medium`. One process step can include multiple media, and one medium can be present in different process steps. Both tables have a primary key.

**Question**

I want to connect these two tables. So I want to be able to see which media belong to a process step, but also which process steps can belong to a medium. What is the best way to go at this?

**Tried:**

I have tried to make a new table, with two columns. One for the primary key of `tbl_uo_step`, and one column for the primary key of `tbl_medium`. I can get this to work, which is not really the problem. The problem is, should this indeed be the correct way to go at it, how do I easily enter the data in this table? It is quite a lot of information and searching for the correct primary key every time will be too time consuming.

[image]

Comment: This question should be in dba.stackexchange not here unless if you are looking for a sql script to which you did not mention

Comment: Hmm I fear you might be right, however, I was also thinking along the lines of adding relationships to the bridge table, which might have needed sql. If applicable, and possible, I'll move the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You have an n:m relation between medium and step, so you build a bridge table as shown. I don't see any problem with that.

To fill the tables: Put all media in the media table, all steps in the steps table, then all relations in the bridge table. Looks easy to me.

To get the data: What should be time consuming about this? You built the tables exactly as needed and a dbms` one purpose is to deal with such tables and get their data quickly. Again, no problem at all here.

Comment: Hmm thank you for the feedback! What I meant with adding data was the part of putting the relations in the bridge table. I know which medium, belongs to which proc step, but the ID's give me no visual reference to the description, which makes it hard to see what I am linking to each other. How would you go at this?

Comment: You are using an ID design here. That means your tables' keys are technical IDs with no meaning. So yes, you have no visual reference as to what IDs you are linking. Either write a programm for this, where you as a user deal with steps and mediums and the program deals with the IDs internally, or use natural keys instead if possible. Or use SQL: `insert into tbl_step_medium (step_id, med_id) values ((select step_id from tbl_uo_step where uo_step_no = 123), (select medium_id from tbl_medium where medium_name = 'Mata Hari'));`

Comment: Thank you Thorsten, your answer in combination with the SQL was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need a foreign key in the tbl_uo_step and use that foreign key as a link from tbl_medium.

In this case you will not need a new table.

Comment: But how can I add multiple media to one row in `tbl_uo_step` then?